# TypeScript - trouble with some advanced Type Inferrence; trying to build better types for Rematch

Tags: typescript, generics

I am currently playing around with advanced TypeScript types -- my quest is (in the mid-term) to improve the [types for rematch](https://github.com/rematch/rematch/blob/master/src/typings.d.ts).

So, what I did so far is:

```
interface ModelDefinition<TState> {
    state: TState;
    reducers: TReducers<TState>;
}
interface TReducers<TState> {
    [reducerName: string]: TReducer<TState>;
}
type TReducer<TState> = (state: TState, payload: any) => TState;

function createModel<TModelDefinition extends ModelDefinition<TModelDefinition["state"]>>(modelDefinition: TModelDefinition): void {
     // ...
}

// Now, this can be used as follows:
createModel({
    state: 42,
    reducers: {
        setValueTo21: (oldState: number, payload: any) => 21
    }
});
```

The system automatically checks at this point if the state matches the first parameter of each reducer; and that the reducer returns the correct state type.

*Note: I am deliberately not using a simple `TState` generic parameter, as when the types would not match, the errors are shown not at the non-matching reducer, but at the state definition.*

With the types above, I am not able to add a new property `effects` which is a *method*. It works if I use lambda syntax.

### Works:

```
createModel({
    state: 42,
    reducers: {
        setValueTo21: (oldState: number, payload: any) => 21
    },
    effects: () => {}
});
```

### breaks:

```
createModel({
    state: 42,
    reducers: {
        setValueTo21: (oldState: number, payload: any) => 21
    },
    effects() {}
});
```

The error message is shown at `setValueTo21` and is:

```
Type '(oldState: number, payload: any) => number' is not assignable to type 'TReducer<unknown>'.
  Types of parameters 'oldState' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'. [2322]
```

### works again:

funnily, when I extract the function definition outside of the body, **no type inference error occurs**:

```
const effects = function() {
}
createModel({
    state: 42,
    reducers: {
        setValueTo21: (oldState: number, payload: any) => 21
    },
    effects
});
```

### Summary

This seems really weird to me. BTW - I am running the newest TypeScript version. Anybody has any hints, maybe what bug I am hitting? (to me it's hard to find even the bug in the TypeScript bug tracker which might have this issue).

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: FYI: my full examples can be found at https://github.com/skurfuerst/typescript-type-exploring/blob/master/types/TYPE_PLAYGROUND.ts

Answer (score 0):

This indeed seems like a bug (probably worth reporting), but the problem is in the way you constrain generic parameter onto itself via accessing `["state"]`. You actually don't need this constraint and can use `any` which has a meaning of "unconstrained" and not literally "any" when used inside an `extends` clause. This works:

```
function createModel<TModel extends ModelDefinition<any>>(modelDefinition: TModel): void {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Hm, the thing is I want to *explicitely* constrain the ModelDefinition to the state passed in there. In case I do not have this constraint, the problem is that you can use a different state shape than what is used inside reducers.

Comment: @SebastianKurfürst what do you mean by "use a different shape"? Could you please add an example in your question of what doesn't work / you want to avoid?